# dynamic VFS endpoint

Tags: dynamic, wso2, endpoint, vfs

I need to create folder on storage. The folder name is dynamic and comes from incoming request. I tried with concatenated full path in property 'transport.vfs.ReplyFileName' without success and still use the uri property in the address endpoint:

```
<property description="concat path and DestinationFolder" expression="fn:concat(get-property('path'),get-property('DFolder'))" name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
            <property description="OUT_ONLY=true" name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/> 
 <endpoint>
    <address uri="vfs:file://D:\\temp_WSO2\\Downloads\\">
    </address>
 </endpoint>
```

Anyone with idea how to solve that situation?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the To [header](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Header+Mediator) property to set a dynamic path. Your  can then contain an anonymous endpoint.

```
<header name="To" expression="fn:concat(get-property('path'),get-property('DFolder'))"/>
<property description="OUT_ONLY=true" name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/> 
<send>
    <endpoint>
        <default/>
    </endpoint>
</send>
```

You can see [examples on the WSO2 documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Header+Mediator#HeaderMediator-Example5-SettingtheendpointURLdynamicallyToHeader).

Comment: Thanks for your support!